# SystemModeler join wires

Tags: system-modeler

I'm using SystemModeler and I'm trying to understand what is the equivalent for Simulink's Ctrl+drag to create a wire coming out of an existing wire. I am trying to make a wire come out of an existing wire in an electrical circuit (create a node essentially) and I am unable to do this.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: You may get a useful reply, but please be aware that this site is exclusively for *Mathematica*, rather than other Wolfram products in general, so most people here will probably not know the answer. A better place to ask may be the Wolfram Community, which has forums for all of the Wolfram products, [including SystemModeler](http://community.wolfram.com/content?curTag=system%20modeler).

Comment: @OleksandrR. Personally I wasn't in favour, but I thought the community decision was that it should be [on topic](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1336/12).  OP: It is true that few people here have SystemModeler expertise and you'll likely get a faster answer on W Community.

Comment: @Szabolcs sorry, I hadn't noticed the vote totals for that. I had thought that we were going to say SystemModeler was off topic unless the question has some relationship to *Mathematica* as well. Okay, so the question is on topic (as you can see, I didn't vote to close).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such functionality in Modelica (the underlying modeling language of SystemModeler).

What you can do is connect two "wires" to the same connector on a component, and they will be considered the same signal.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do this, but it's a shame that such a simple feature is not available!

Comment: I work on SystemModeler at Wolfram, I'll forward your feedback. Thanks!